# How to serialize xml request posted on WebAPI

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I have two type of request and in both the requests difference is only of the root element so I want to reuse the internal contents 
these messages are being posted to web API endpoint so they should be serialized automatically but not sure how to achieve this, 
can anyone help me with this, please?

```
<Reprocess>
   <request>
     <Title>Mrs</Title>
     <ForeName>Lucy</ForeName>
 </request>
</Reprocess>

<NewApplication>
  <request>
   <Title>Mrs</Title>
   <ForeName>Lucy</ForeName>
  </request>
</NewApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove root of the xml and than serialize to your internal contents.

```
            var xmlString1 = "<Reprocess><request><Title>Mrs</Title><ForeName>Lucy</ForeName></request></Reprocess>";
        var xmlString2 = "<NewApplication><request><Title>Mrs</Title><ForeName>Lucy</ForeName></request></NewApplication>";

        XDocument input = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString1));
        XDocument input2 = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xmlString2)); ;

        XElement firstChild = input.Root.Elements().First();
        Console.WriteLine(firstChild.ToString());


        XElement firstChild2 = input.Root.Elements().First();
        Console.WriteLine(firstChild2.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but as per this logic it seems we need to write our own formatter but I want to use inbuilt xml serializer.